# How do I use an image in a frame without using a label?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to use an image in a tk.Frame without using a Label inside of that frame. So that I can overlay other widgets like tk.Label on that Frame. Making the frame serve as a background.

Here's an Image of what I want:

[image: What I'm trying to make]

The image will be a gradient, with an extension of ".png".

I've tried using the Image in the frame, but there is no "img" argument for a frame. Only a Label has that argument. (it seems)

Comment: If you want transparent text over image, you need to use `Canvas` instead of `Frame`.

Comment: The background of a Label, just like all Tkinter widgets, is an opaque, solid-colored rectangle, specified solely by the widget itself - the color of any containing or overlapped widget is irrelevant.  So it's not physically possible to achieve your goal of text on a gradient background with Labels.  The ONLY way to do this is within a single Canvas, using an image item and text items.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use an image in a frame without using a label?

The simplest solution is to not use a frame. You can use a `Label` everywhere you can use a `Frame` (ie: you can pack/grid other widgets inside a label). You could also use a `Canvas` instead of a `Label`.

If you insist on using a frame, then you have to put some other widget that supports images inside the frame. The most common examples are a `Label` or a `Canvas`.